# Jquery bind change don't work on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, bind, onchange

I want to bind a change event on a dynamic input checkbox element but it's strange...

This code works :

```
$("form").on('change', 'input:checkbox.checkbox_main', function () {
            console.log('change ok');
        });
```

This one don't works :

```
$('input:checkbox.checkbox_main').on('change', function () {
            console.log('change ok');
        });
```

Can anybody explain me why ?

I read everywhere that the bind function is deprecated in jquery v3.1 so what does I use for replacement ? What is the good way for catch the change event on a dynamic checkbox ?

Comment: Yes this is event delegation for more reference https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate | http://javascript.info/tutorial/event-delegation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document` is container and considered as DOM.

when you try to access `$('input:checkbox.checkbox_main').on('change')` it won't work because jQuery couldn't identify the HTML element was available at the time of `document.ready`.

`$("form").on('change', 'input:checkbox.checkbox_main'` this will specifically bind the event dynamically to the container for specific element.

Further specification,

`$('body')` targets the `<body>` html element, while `$(document)` targets the entire html document. That means if you want to reference something in the `<head>` element you want to get there by `$(document)`.

FYI, I assume that `input:checkbox.checkbox_main` element in dynamically added to the DOM.

Comment: I read everywhere that the bind function is deprecated in jquery v3.1 so what does I use for replacement ?

Comment: `.on()` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The **1st** `event` is `bound` on the `form` and the `change` is executed on any children elements matching the `selector`. So if you add any dynamic elements in there, they will be caught.

The **2nd** `event` matches the elements that currently exist in the `DOM` at the moment of executing the `selector`. So any new elements will **not** be picked up.

**EDIT**

If you have a dynamic menu like this:

```
<ul id='topMenu'>
   <li></li>
</ul>
```

And you would like to bind any events on its children (including all the possible ones) I would do this:

```
$('#topMenu').on('click', 'li', function() {

});
```

Many people would just stick to the DOM `$(document).on('click', '...` but I like to keep my code clear and precise so I always choose the lowest possible parent container

Comment: So how to replace the bind event correctly ? with the first exemple ?

Comment: @arno - It depends on which `element` is **static** on your page. I always find the lowest possible parent container and bind the events of its children to it. many people always use the `DOM` but I try to be a bit more clever than that.